# Remap plugin command with plugin command + vim shortcuts

Tags: vim-windows, normal-mode

I'm using rails.vim with the command `:AS` which open the alternate file (like `test`) and split the window.

The problem is, it's always on the top and I would like to open it below the current window. I would like to know if it's possible to merge these two commands properly?

I'm able to do it with `:execute 'AS' | wincmd J` but is this the best way to to it?

How can I be sure it goes just below?

And how do I add it to a leader key?

Comment: I would suggest you create your own command that call exactly what you already have. The plugin does not seems to provide this level of customisation. As for the leader key, you can do `nnoremap <leader>as :execute 'AS' | wincmd J`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in different forms.

Use the command you already created and bind this to a mapping (here with the leader key):

```
nnoremap <leader>as :execute 'AS' <bar> wincmd J<CR>
```

Or you can create a new command that acts the same way (B for below):

```
command! ASB :execute 'AS' | wincmd J
```

But using `wincmd J` is overwhelming, prefer the split commands :

```
:abo[veleft] {cmd}
:bel[owright] {cmd}
```

So you can have your mapping/command like so:

```
nnoremap <leader>as :bel AS<CR>
command! ASB :bel AS
```

Note that if you **always** want to open a split below you can set the option in your `vimrc`:

```
set splitbelow
```

See also:

- `:h abo`
- `:h bel`
- `:h command`
- `:h <leader>`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, comment and proposal. If I do `nnoremap <leader>as :execute 'AS' | wincmd J` when I do the leader command. I see on the command line `execute 'AS'` but nothing happen. `nnoremap <leader>as :bel AS<cr>` execute AS command but not the window mouvement.

Comment: Updated, does it work now?

Comment: `nnoremap <leader>as :execute 'AS' <bar> wincmd J<CR>` works perfectly ! No success with `nnoremap <leader>as :bel AS<CR>` :) Still open on the top of the window